# How does DVD CSS/CPPM protection actually work?

Tags: dvd, copy-protection, disk-protection

When I try to burn a DVD with ImgBurn I get a message that the disc is copy protected:

> Copyright protection system type: CSS/CPPM

I've been trying to Google on how this protection actually works, all I could find is that there's some secret sectors on the cd that are used for decryption of the data.

However I'm wondering - how is this enforced (someone has to "know" that those sectors should be read by the secret decryption key) - is this some sort of specification on the DVD drive? or perhaps some specification that the operating system "knows" about and therefor decrypts the data successfully?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Scramble_System ! I remember the controversy when the decryption program was leaked, and its distribution is still legally questionable in many places.

Comment: @pjc50 - After reading that Wikipedia now I understand that the drive enforces the encryption. I just didn't manage to find the correct Wikipedia until you posted it.. so Please post it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After reading about it on the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Scramble_System) that user pjc50 posted in his comment, I understand that it's the drive that enforces the encryption.